# SoapUI and web service testing with windows authentication

Tags: asp.net, web-services, testing, proxy, soapui

> Blockquote

I'm trying to test an already deployed web service through SoapUI. The service URL is https://hostname:82/Service.asmx. I modified the test Endpoint to reflect this. Web requests go through a proxy that uses Windows Authentication.

First I attempted to run the test directly but without success. All I got was an error:

> 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials

Next, I entered proxy details and domain username/password into SoapUI proxy settings. This creates another error:

> status#   HTTP/1.1 502 Proxy Error ( The specified Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) port is not allowed. Forefront TMG is not configured to allow
>   SSL requests from this port. Most Web browsers use port 443 for SSL requests.  )

I wasn't really paying attention to this until now so I ignored the error and went on to install Burp Suite hoping that this would help with Windows Authentication. I got the Internet working through Burp Suite but soapUI still doesn't do anything and I can't run any tests. This time the error is a bit different:

> XML Parsing Error: syntax error Location:
>   https://hostname:82/Service.asmx Line Number 1, Column 1:Burp proxy
>   error: failed to connect to IP.

What am I doing wrong? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out in the end. I configured Burp proxy the wrong way. Instead of redirecting to my WS server, I was redirecting to our internet proxy which of course didn't know what to do.